# Como puedo subir un proyecto con Angular y Laravel a GitHub

Tags: laravel, angular, github, laravel-6, angular9

Tengo un proyecto con un back-end en laravel y con un front-end en Angular, ambas carpetas están en htdocs (local). Necesito ir metiendo ese proyecto en un repositorio Git ya que lo tengo bastante avanzado y no quiero que me pete. mi pregunta es ¿los voy subiendo por separado? o ¿existe alguna manera de poder subir los dos a la vez?. Recuerdo que estan en carpetas separadas una con una instalación laravel y otra con Angular 9. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En los proyecto que he visto en angular, suelo tener los repos separados. Ya que en cada proyecto tiene su .gititnore para evitar subir archivos innecesarios.

Aparte uno nunca sabe cuando su backend podría cambiar.